# git shortlog - print the body of commits

Tags: git

Is it possible to use `git shortlog` for showing the full commits bodies?

I want the output to be:

```
$ git shortlog 
John Doe (2):
      Commit title
        commit body
      Commit title
        commit body
```

No success for doing so using the `--format` flag.

`--format=%B` just just stays the same, and `--format=%b` gives only the first line of body.

Comment: Try `--format='%s %b'`. It outputs more but still not all. The footers are missing. And as @torek points out, the output is always one line. The placeholder `%n` only expands to a space instead of a newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

`git shortlog`'s purpose in life is to summarize commits into one-line descriptions, which then get sorted by author.  As such, it reads up to one *line* of whatever is going to become the one-line description ... and then throws away anything else, so only the one line matters.  You can choose what goes into the one line, but it has to be one line, and all on one line.

The `git shortlog` program is not really all that complicated: given your desired output format, you could probably write yourself a perl or awk script to do it in a few minutes.